# Datatable column-widths-mode="auto" creates horizontal scrollbar on table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

When I set `column-widths-mode="auto"` on a `<lightning-datatable>`, I notice there appears a horizontal scrollbar. This seems to be a bug. Anyone know anything about this, or how to fix?

(example: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/3udYYsFQZiHsNNqwUqPk)

Comment: What's your expectation? If there's not enough room to squeeze all columns, I believe it's expected to see a horizontal scrollbar. For example, I didn't see a horizonal scrollbar on my screen when I opened your example - I had to resize the horizontal view to be tighter until it displayed.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - I'm seeing a scrollbar even when all the header text fits just fine. And the content in the cells in the rows should clip if it doesn't fit, so that shouldn't cause a scrollbar.

Comment: Interesting. Have you tested in a sandbox just to confirm it behaves the same? Playing around with the width, I do see random times where the edge of the last column box seems to be clipped (and the horizontal bar appears) even though it shouldn't.

Comment: Same with me and it is 2022 :(